# R list to dataframe

Tags: r

Im have list, and im want convert this into dataframe

```
lst<-NULL
lst[[1]] <- c(1,2,3)
lst[[2]] <- c(1,2,3,4)
lst[[3]] <- c(1,2)
```

im need get dataframe

```
1|2|3|NA
1|2|3|4|
1|2|NA|NA|
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `plyr`:

```
library(plyr)

ldply(lst, rbind)
#  1 2  3  4
#1 1 2  3 NA
#2 1 2  3  4
#3 1 2 NA NA
```

Answer (score 7):

One way in `base R`

```
do.call(rbind,lapply(lst, function(x) {length(x) <- max(lengths(lst));x}))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    2    3   NA
#[2,]    1    2    3    4
#[3,]    1    2   NA   NA
```

When a `length` greater than the length of a vector is assigned, `NA` values will fill in for the empty space. We find the longest vector in the list with `max(lengths(lst))`. Then assign that to each vector and `rbind` the list. If you would like a data frame as output, you can use `do.call(rbind.data.frame, ..)`.

The function `lengths` was added to `R 3.2.0`. It is equivalent to `sapply(lst, length)`.

**second method**

If you don't think there will be a performance hit from transposing the matrix, you can also try:

```
t(sapply(lst, function(x) {length(x) <- max(lengths(lst));x}))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    2    3   NA
# [2,]    1    2    3    4
# [3,]    1    2   NA   NA
```

Comment: `\`length<-\`(x, max(lengths(lst)))`, if you want to go `{}`less. Shorter still: `do.call(rbind,lapply(lst, \`length<-\`, max(lengths(lst))))`

Comment: excited to find out about the addition of the `lengths` function -- i am still using R 3.0.3. and was unaware of this. useful!